# For loop in WebBrowser module doesn't work

Tags: python, for-loop, browser, hyperlink, python-webbrowser

I have some links in a list and I need to open all these links in my browser

```
import webbrowser
browserpath='C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'

lis=[ITS FILLED WITH LINK ADDRESSES]

for site in lis:
    webbrowser.get(browserpath).open_new_tab(site)
```

it just executes and finishing the program but nothing opens

I'm using Python 3.11.1

upd.

It seems it's working fine without webbrowser.get()

Another question is: how would I specify which browser I need them to be opened with?
If I need to open it with Firefox I would try:

```
import webbrowser
lis = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.youtube.com", "https://www.facebook.com"]
fire="C:\programs\Browser\firefox.exe %s"
for site in lis:
    webbrowser.get(fire).open_new_tab(site)
```

but it doesn't work too, can you explain it to me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `webbrowser.get` which returns a controller object for the browser type. If you do this, you should then use that object to open sites. e.g.

```
import webbrowser

lis = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.youtube.com", "https://www.facebook.com"]

fire="C:\programs\Browser\firefox.exe"

controller = webbrowser.get(using=fire)

for url in urls:
    controller.open(url, new=2)  # Open in a new tab if possible
```

(Ensure that your path to your browser executable is correct of course.)

If you just want the default browser suitable for the launch environment, you can use this:

```
import webbrowser

urls = ["https://stackoverflow.com", "https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser"]

for url in urls:
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2)  # Open in a new tab in same default browser if possible
```